# chroot under Mac OS X

Tags: mac, unix, chroot

So I have googled a lot with different search terms, but didn't find anything usable, only that intead of `ldd` I have to use `otool -L` to see the used libraries of a programm.

I tried to copy bash into ~/chroot/bin and used above named tool to find it's dependcies and stored them there as well (well, of course, i made it look like the real path. /usr became ~/chroot/usr etc).

But when I try to use `sudo chroot ~/chroot`, it tells me that `there is no file or directory` of my shell. Wat.

I need to chroot into a "save" environment to compile a package that will be run in a chrooted environment as well. Specificately, I can not get `php` to compile static:

```
Kevins-MacBook-Air:System Ingwie$ otool -L ./bin/php
./bin/php:
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
    /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libedit.3.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt.4.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.8.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libltdl.3.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib (compatibility version 20.0.0, current version 20.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
    /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.8.0)
    /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.8, current version 47.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.8, current version 47.1.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.4.0)
```

Changing the `makefile` from `-export-dynamic` to `-all-static` and such tricks didnt do a thing. It'll still compile like that. So to get aorund this, I want to chroot. the package will use an entrence script to reproduce the chroot and will operate from there.

Comment: Is `dyld` available inside the chroot?